# How do I structure the file and directory Rake tasks within a regular task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I want to generate the file `my.db` in the `db/` directory. I'm unfamiliar with how to structure the `file` and `directory` tasks within a regular `task`. Help!

```
task :create, [:name, :type] do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:name => "mydb", :type => "mysql")
  directory "db"
  file "db/my.db" => "db" do
    sh "echo 'Hello db' > db/my.db"
  end
  puts "Create a '#{args.type}' database called '#{args.name}'"
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following code will create the db and file unless the already exist...

*You can use this if you wish to have the commands in a single rake task*

```
Dir.mkdir("db") unless Dir.exists?("db")
unless File.exists?("db/my.db")
  File.open("db/my.db", 'w') do |f|
    f.write("Hello db")
  end
end
```

*If you wish to use the file task provided by rake you would need to do this...*

```
# Rakefile
directory "db"

file "db/my.db" => 'db' do
  sh "echo 'Hello db' > db/my.db"
end

task :create => "db/my.db" do 
end
```

In this example your actually telling rake to create tasks called "db" and "db/my.db" which have the side effect of creating the directory or file.

Hope this helps, sorry for the initial confusion :)

Comment: Thank you, your code is corrent, but make me confused is that why we need the `file` flag(as my question) to build a generating file task in rake.

Comment: Hi I have updated the initial post with a rake specific example.

Comment: But we need to pass the parameters to our "file task", how should we fix the code in the second solution of your answer.

Comment: Arguments in rake are used as you have them in your original code. (task :create, [:name, :type] do |t, args|)

Passing parameters from task to task isn't really how rake is designed to work, after all its a build tool, so its supposed to build up a common set of assets for a project.

I'm sorry I can't be of any more help :(

Comment: Checking my answer edited, i did it with that way of passing the parameters from task to task. But it looks like very strange if we do it as this way.